# Getting an error saying "Cast from "String" to unrelated type NSDictionary always fails". I get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, alamofire

I'm getting an error on the let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary line. Any possible ways to help me fix this issue.

```
@objc func registerUser(button: UIButton) {

    //Creating parameters for post request
    let parameters: Parameters = ["username": userName.text!, "password": passWord.text!, "email": emailField.text!, "name": nameField.text!]

    //Sending http post request
    Alamofire.request(urlUserRegister, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseString {

        response in
        //printing response
        print(response)

        //getting the json value from the server
        if let result = response.result.value {

            //Convert as NSDictionary
            let jsonData = result as! NSDictionary //This is where the error occcurs

            //displaying the message in label
            self.messageLabel.text = jsonData.value(forKey: "message") as? String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. You are using `responseString` instead of `responseJSON`. 2. This is Swift. Use `Dictionary` instead of `NSDictionary`.

Comment: The error message clearly says that `result` is `String` not `Dictionary`. And don't use `NSDictionary` in Swift. You are fighting the strong type system. Use native type `[String:Any]`. And never use `value(forKey` in this case. Use key subscription.

Comment: @the4kman when I use responseJSON , I get this error. FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: then the json is not well formated

Comment: You should print out the returned `JSON` you get and post it, telling us about your expectation and result. That way we might get an idea on what goes wrong. This way it is pure guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `responseString` and put instead `responseJSON`

```
Alamofire.request(urlUserRegister, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON {

    if let result = response.result.value as? [String:Any] {

        if let message = result["message"] as? String {
            print(message)
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: When I do this, I get "Generic parameter "Key" could not be inferred in Cast to Dictionary".

Comment: i guess it's a json problem